# Are or was, which is right?

Tags: tense

His eyes **are/were** so blue that I thought they were like diamonds.

I envied him because he **has/had** blue eyes

Which is right in each sentence?
Each verb indicates constant fact, so doesn't have to maintain verb agreement?

Answer (score 1):

> His eyes are/were so blue that I thought they were like diamonds.

As far as this goes, use either present or past tense depending on how confident you are that the trait still actually applies. In this example, if you just saw the person this morning and you saw that his eyes are still blue, use "are." If you think the person might have died or lost the trait, then use "were."

It's fine if the tenses don't match up - you're saying that in the past you thought his eyes were like diamonds (with the implication that you don't think that in the present.)

> I envied him because he **had** blue eyes

Generally you do want to want to align the tenses. In the past, you envied him because his eyes were blue, in the past. Consider this:

> I envied him because he had a really nice car.

Well, this sentence still would be true if he doesn't have the car in the present, and you wouldn't use "has" if he didn't have the car in the present.